# Best way to scale large images

Tags: java, android

Is there is best tool to scale multiple images for android studios. I have tried the Android Drawable importer and various other but i keep getting the out of memory error

I am making images in Adobe illustrator if i import the image for android scaling i get my images in different densities like which i believe is too high

Result form Adobe Illustrator After scaling

```
for l-dpi 

810 x 1440

for m-dpi

1080 x 1920 

for h-dpi 


1620 x 2880

for xhdpi

2160 x3840

for xxhdpi

3240 x 5760

for xxxhdpi

4320 x 7680
```

My images pixels that i use in project but till getting outOfMemoryException :

```
for l-dpi 

151 x 270 (seven images that have these dimensions)
191 x 284 (other seven images that have these dimensions)

for m-dpi

202 x 360 
255 x 379 

for hdpi

303 x 540
382 x 569

xhdpi

405 x 720
510 x 759

xxhdpi

607 x 1080
765 x 1139

xxxhdpi

810 x 1440
1020 x 1519
```

My project contain a lot of images so any easy way to do scaling properly on large scale

Comment: Have you tried using [BitmapFactory.Options](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options)?

Comment: Nope i did not try this class

Comment: use this site to change the size of image https://tinypng.com/ . And copy paste in to your android studio

Answer (score 0):

Besides reduicng size, you clearly should try reducing their bit depth to exactly 8 bits as well. by default full color is 32 bits that's 4x as big.

Comment: can i change their depth in adobe illustrator ! BTW thanks i will try that

Comment: i will let you know .. let me try

Comment: Does it matter what bits the image is ??

Comment: @SaadZahoor yes it clearly does matter, because the more bits per pixel are used, the more is total size, it's exactly the law of number multiplication